# Neural network function

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am using NeurophStudio and I am trying to train the network to learn the function:

f(x) = 0   if x < 0.3 |
       0.7 if x > 0.3

Any idea if I can do this using a neuronal network and if yes how? I tried using a perceptron and a multilayer perceptron but no luck yet.

Thanks,
Andrei

Answer (score 0):

Take a [heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) as the activation function. You can find more information [here](http://www.learnartificialneuralnetworks.com/).

[image]